# How can I create a Group_Concat field per table using values from other records

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

Suppose a table of First and Last Names and for each record I want to do comma-delimited list of relatives.

- 1ST | LAST | RELATIVES
- Bob | Smith | Alice,Andrew
- Alice | Smith | Bob,Andrew
- Andrew |Smith | Bob,Alice
- Alex | Jones | Anny, Ricky
- Anny | Jones | Alex, Ricky
- Ricky | Jones | Alex, Anny

As per this sqlFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25d80c/1

I know how to group_contact manually for any last name but am unclear how for each record I could have it go find the records with matching last name and run the same group_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a self `LEFT` join and aggregation:

```
SELECT s1.First, s1.Last,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s2.First) Relatives
FROM Surnames s1 LEFT JOIN Surnames s2
ON s2.Last = s1.Last AND s2.First <> s1.First
GROUP BY s1.First, s1.Last;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6cb4b942e26bfeb16cece8dce26579f).

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Any idea how to run as an Update? I've tried every which way but that Group By is not liked in any of them.

Comment: @user3649739 an aggregation query can't be used as it is in an UPDATE statement. It must be joined to the table that is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the aggregation in a `lateral join`, like so:

```
select s.First, s.Last, r.Relatives
from Surnames s,
lateral (
  select group_concat(First) Relatives
  from Surnames r
  where s.Last = r.Last AND s.First != r.First
)r
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46a7480eace6bd9fbb984e3831f57496)